# Parse: Grab photo during background job

Tags: javascript, ios, parsing

I'm uploading images to Parse via iOS in a similar way to this tutorial (https://github.com/ParsePlatform/SavingImagesTutorial) and want to grab them in a Parse Cloud Code Background Job. Right now Parse is returning a success with no results when I run this function. Any ideas?

```
Parse.Cloud.job("photoPing", function(request, status) {
  var query = new Parse.Query("UserPhoto");
  query.each(function(userphoto) {
      console.log(userphoto);
  }).then(function() {
    status.success("Win");
  }, function(error) {
    status.error("Womp");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out my ACL controls https://parse.com/docs/data#security-objects weren't set to public. All good now.